# How to require gradient only for some tensor elements in a pytorch tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I like to use a tensor with only a few variable elements which are considered during the backpropagation step. Consider for example:

```
self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, 3, 1, padding=1, bias=False)
mask = torch.zeros(self.conv1.weight.data.shape, requires_grad=False)
self.conv1.weight.data[0, 0, 0, 0] += mask[0, 0, 0, 0]
print(self.conv1.weight.data[0, 0 , 0, 0].requires_grad)
```

It will be output **False**

Answer (score 4):

You can only switch on and off gradient computation at the tensor level which means that the `requires_grad` ***is not*** element-wise. What you observe is different because you have accessed the `requires_grad` attribute of `conv1.weight.data` which is not the same object as its wrapper tensor `conv1.weight`!

Notice the difference:

```
>>> conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, 3) # requires_grad=True by default

>>> conv1.weight.requires_grad
True

>>> conv1.weight.data.requires_grad
False
```

`conv1.weight` is the weight tensor while `conv1.weight.data` is the underlying data tensor which never requires gradient because it is at a different level.

---

Now onto how to solve the ***partially requiring gradient computation on a tensor***. Instead of looking at solving it as *"only require gradient for some elements of tensor"*, you can think of it as *"don't require gradient for some elements of tensor"*. You can do so by overwriting the gradient values on the tensor at the desired positions after the backward pass:

```
>>> conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 1, 2)
>>> mask = torch.ones_like(conv1.weight)
```

For example, to prevent the update of the first component of the convolutional layer:

```
>>> mask[0,0,0,0] = 0
```

After the backward pass, you can mask the gradient on `conv1.weight`:

```
>>> conv1(torch.rand(1,3,10,10)).mean().backward()
>>> conv1.weight.grad *= mask
```